# How do you import a particular record in a database to your system and convert it to string for comparison?

Tags: vb.net, string, validation, comparison, case-sensitive

Here's the deal, it's a log in form and I need to put case-sensitive validation, in other words if your Username = Admin then Admin != admin

Consider this code block (VB is really unfamiliar for me so break it to me gently ^^)
This is after it has matched a record in the database to the parameter passed to the function LogIn()

```
If dataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'case-sensitive Validation follows
        'data in Column ID and Password are placed in variables
        'which are then compared to the arguments sent using the Compare() function
        Dim strID = dataTable.Columns("U_ID").
        Dim strPass = dataTable.Columns("Password")
        Dim idResult As Integer 'both results will hold the value of String.Compare()
        Dim passwordResult As Integer

        *idResult = String.Compare(strID, ID)
```

the asterisk-ed line returns an error (obviously) as strId is not of data type String.
That's my dilemma.

I also tried using LIKE but again since strId and strPass are not Strings, all I get is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Dim strID = dataTable.Columns("U_ID")
```

to this:

```
Dim strID as String = dataTable.Columns("U_ID").ToString
```